# Configure IReport and Firebird

Tags: java, jasper-reports, firebird, jaybird

I am using iReport for jasper report. My Backend database is in firebird. I am trying to configure iReport with the firebird but couldn't succeed. I have added the firebird jar file in the classpath of iReport GUI. After that i add the firebird in the services of the iReport. Services window shows me the firebird driver. after that when i right-click on the driver and then connect using selected i got a window in which i have to put my credentials.

```
user Nmae: sysdba
password : masterkey
JDBC URL: jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:C:\Users\waqas\Desktop\MOBILESTORE.fdb
```

When i click on ok button. My iReport goes to connecting to database mode and after long time it didn't response. It still connecting to firebird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that you actually have Firebird installed and your Firebird is running as a service. The user account running the Firebird service does not have access to your user profile and therefor is unable to open a database file in `C:\Users\waqas\Desktop\MOBILESTORE.fdb`. Put the file in a location that is accessible to all users (or specifically to the user linked to the Firebird service), say `C:\Databases\`.

That said, I would actually expect this scenario to result in an error almost immediately, so it might be a different problem.

**EDIT**

You indicate in the comments, that you receive a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver`. This means that you did not add the Jaybird JDBC driver to the classpath of iReport.

You can download the Jaybird (Firebird JDBC) driver from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/

I don't use iReport myself, but according to [this tutorial](http://rediantosatya.wordpress.com/2011/12/19/how-to-add-new-jdbc-driver-in-jaspersoft-ireport/) you can add the driver under Tools > Options > iReport, tab Classpath. You need to add `jaybird-full-2.2.3.jar`, **OR** `jaybird-2.2.3.jar` and `connector-api-1.5.jar` (from the lib folder in the Jaybird zip).

**EDIT 2**

I have just downloaded iReport and tried it myself. There are basically two ways of making a database connection to Firebird from iReport, both work for me:

### Database JDBC connection

The first option is *Database JDBC connection*, this requires the driver to be on the classpath:

1. Go to Tools, Options, iReport, Classpath and add `jaybird-full-2.2.3.jar`
2. Click on the create datasource icon on the welcome tab
3. Select Database JDBC connection and click Next
4. Give the datasource a name
5. For JDBC driver enter `org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver`
6. For URL enter the JDBC url for your database (eg `jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/D:/data/db/employee.fdb`)
7. Enter username and password

A click on test should show *"Connection test successful!"*. Now you can use the database connection.

### NetBeans Database JDBC connection

The other method of connecting is *NetBeans Database JDBC connection*

1. Go to Window, Services
2. Expand the Databases service
3. Right click on Drivers, New Driver
4. Under Driver file(s) add `jaybird-full-2.2.3.jar`
5. Driver Class and Name are filled in automatically; click OK
6. Right click the new Firebird (JCA/JDBC driver) entry and select Connect using
7. Enter username and password, and the JDBC url, click ok
8. Click the create datasource icon
9. Select NetBeans Database JDBC connection
10. Enter a name and select the connection from the dropdown

Comment: no its not working. same issue that iReport try to connect with firebird and then didn't respond. When i try to connect with the firebird database using database wizard. i put following credentials

JDBC Driver : org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
JDBC URL:jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:C:\Database\MOBILESTORE.fdb
and then passowrd and user name i entered. when i click on test button i got following exception

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver

what does it mean? i think it means fire bird jar file is in not the iReport class path?

Comment: @WaqasAli Don't you think it would have been relevant to include that exception in your question? I read your question as 'nothing happens/it hangs'. I will update my answer.

Comment: JayBird JDBC driver is already in the classpath. i have also added the connector jar file in the class path but it didn't work i got same exception. can you look this this url http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/510828/ireport-firebird
its saying something about the dll library

Comment: Jaybird doesn't need the dll unless you want to use Firebird embedded or insist on using the native client instead of the - default - pure java driver.

Comment: If Jaybird is on the classpath of the application, you wouldn't get the exception you have in your first comment.

Comment: I have added the firebird in the class path. I am also confuse why i am getting exception while firebird is in the class path. I think i am missing something. if you want to share my class path screen i can show you the pic of the configuration

Comment: Can you tell me which version of iReport you downloaded??

Comment: I tried it with iReport version 5.1.0. Maybe a 'stupid' question, but you do have a Firebird server installed, right?

Comment: Yes i have firebird installed i am using flamerobin as a GUI of firebird. I have used firebird driver for the connectivity of java and firebird every thing goes fine except this iReport and firebird connectivity.

Comment: thanks for your time your really help me. May be there is some other issue.

Comment: I don't know what happen but today its work. I do nothing just add jar driver of firebird again and now i got successfully connection with the firebird.